# MVCContrib Grid showing headers when empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

The elegant [Action Syntax](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/03/01/mvccontrib-grid-part-5-the-action-syntax/) in the MVCContrib Grid gives us the `Empty()` method. However, the default behavior of `MvcContrib.UI.Grid.GridRenderer<T>.RenderHeader()` is to *hide* the table column headers when the grid is empty. Is there a way to show headers when data is not present that does not require a major refactoring?

Now I have heard of **hiding the headers by default** and hard-coding something but this is not cool to me.

By the way, this is what is happening under the hood (in `MvcContrib.UI.Grid.GridRenderer<T>`):

```
protected virtual bool RenderHeader()
{
    //No items - do not render a header.
    if(! ShouldRenderHeader()) return false;

    RenderHeadStart();

    foreach(var column in VisibleColumns())
    {
        //Allow for custom header overrides.
        if(column.CustomHeaderRenderer != null)
        {
            column.CustomHeaderRenderer(new RenderingContext(Writer, Context, _engines));
        }
        else
        {
            RenderHeaderCellStart(column);
            RenderHeaderText(column);
            RenderHeaderCellEnd();
        }
    }

    RenderHeadEnd();

    return true;
}

protected virtual bool ShouldRenderHeader()
{
    return !IsDataSourceEmpty();
}

protected bool IsDataSourceEmpty()
{
    return DataSource == null || !DataSource.Any();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom Grid Renderer (subclass `GridRenderer<T>`) use overrides like these:

```
/// <summary>
/// Renders the <c>table</c> header.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// Returns the negative of the results
/// of <see cref="GridRenderer<T>.IsDataSourceEmpty"/>.
/// </returns>
/// <remarks>
/// The return value of <see cref="GridRenderer<T>.IsDataSourceEmpty"/>
/// in this override has no effect on whether the Grid header is rendered.
/// 
/// However, this return value is used
/// by <see cref="GridRenderer<T>.Render"/>
/// to run <see cref="GridRenderer<T>.RenderItems"/>
/// or <see cref="GridRenderer<T>.RenderEmpty"/>.
/// </remarks>
protected override bool RenderHeader()
{
    RenderHeadStart();

    foreach(var column in VisibleColumns())
    {
        //Allow for custom header overrides.
        if(column.CustomHeaderRenderer != null)
        {
            column.CustomHeaderRenderer(new RenderingContext(Writer, Context, _engines));
        }
        else
        {
            RenderHeaderCellStart(column);
            RenderHeaderText(column);
            RenderHeaderCellEnd();
        }
    }

    RenderHeadEnd();

    return !base.IsDataSourceEmpty();
}
```

…

```
protected override void RenderEmpty()
{
    RenderBodyStart();
    WriteNoRecordsAvailable(base.Writer, this._numberOfTableColumns);
    RenderBodyEnd();
}
```

Note that `WriteNoRecordsAvailable()` is my custom method so it can be ignored.

Finally:

```
/// <summary>
/// This private member is duplicated
/// in order to override <see cref="GridRenderer<T>.RenderHeader"/>.
/// </summary>
readonly ViewEngineCollection _engines;
```

…

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CrmHtmlTableGridRenderer&lt;T&gt;"/> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="engines">The engines.</param>
public CrmHtmlTableGridRenderer(ViewEngineCollection engines)
    : base(engines)
{
    _engines = engines;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can override the `ShouldRenderHeader()` method of the `HtmlTableGridRenderer` class.

```
public class AlwaysRenderHeaderRenderer<T>
    : HtmlTableGridRenderer<T> where T : class
{
    protected override bool ShouldRenderHeader()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

<%= Html.Grid(Model).RenderUsing(new AlwaysRenderHeaderRenderer<TypeOfModel>()) %>
```

A side effect of this approach is that when the grid is empty, an empty table body will be rendered instead of a message. Any text provided to `Empty()` is ignored. This wasn't a problem for me since I'm manipulating the table on the client side with JavaScript anyway, but be warned.

Answer (score 4):

When inheriting from `HtmlTableGridRenderer` you can also override `RenderEmpty` to eliminate the problem Brant ran into.

```
protected override void RenderEmpty()
    {
        RenderHeadStart();
        foreach(var column in VisibleColumns())
        {
            RenderHeaderCellStart(column);
            RenderHeaderText(column);
            RenderHeaderCellEnd(); 
        }
        RenderHeadEnd();
        RenderBodyStart();
        RenderText("<tr><td colspan=\"" + VisibleColumns().Count() + "\">" + GridModel.EmptyText + "</td></tr>");
        RenderBodyEnd();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just comment out the check to see if it should render the header.  Am I missing something or do you want it to always display the header?

If so then comment out that line.

```
//if(! ShouldRenderHeader()) return false;
```

I haven't looks at all the code but from your code snippet it seems like that should work.

Comment: I don't want to disable default functionality in MVCContrib... we need to look for formal extensibility points...

Comment: I see now... I already have a 'formal extensibility point' working; it is sub-classing `GridRenderer<T>`---all I have to do (it seems) is override `RenderHeader()`...

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6270590/139560) and [Brant's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624914/139560) answers:

```
protected override bool ShouldRenderHeader()
{
    return true;
}

// Oddly Render relies on ShouldRenderHeader to return IsDataSourceEmpty
// so RenderItems will always be called.
protected override void RenderItems()
{
    if (IsDataSourceEmpty())
        RenderEmpty();
    else
        base.RenderItems();
}

protected override void RenderEmpty()
{
    RenderBodyStart();
    RenderText("<tr><td colspan=\"" + VisibleColumns().Count() + "\">" + GridModel.EmptyText + "</td></tr>");
    RenderBodyEnd();
}
```